# How to display images in this code

Tags: java, android

Im trying to display two images in this code `nature2` and `nature4` which need to be displayed in one `Fragment` dynamically - first image `nature2` together with text `"Fragment"` and after swipe `nature4` with text `"Fragment2"`.

The code doesn't show any errors yet I all I get when running is text `"Fragment1"`, after swipe `"Fragment2"` etc..

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private ArrayList<String> strs;

    private FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("x", "onCreateActivity");


        // create an custom array list of your object class here which you can pass to pager adapter
        strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        strs.add("Fragment 1");
        strs.add("Fragment 2");
        strs.add("Fragment 3");
        strs.add("Fragment 4");
        strs.add("Fragment 5");


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), strs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> itemData;
        Fragment fragment;
        int resId;



        public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> itemData) {
            super(fm);
            this.itemData = itemData;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            Log.i("x", "destroyItem");
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.i("x", "getItem");
            // pass data to fragment
            String str = itemData.get(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                resId = R.drawable.nature2;
            } else if (position == 1) {
                resId = R.drawable.nature4;
            }
            fragment = Fragment1.newInstance(str, resId);
            return fragment;

        }
    }

}
```

And Fragment.class

```
 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public  Fragment1(){}

    String stringValue;
    int imagesResId;
    TextView textView;

    private int [] images = {R.drawable.nature2,R.drawable.nature4};

    // static method to create the Fragment1 frag containing string
    public  static Fragment1 newInstance(String str, int imagesResId)
    {
        Fragment1 slider=new Fragment1();
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("stringValue", str);
        b.putInt("images",imagesResId);
        slider.setArguments(b);
        return slider;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("x","onCreateViewFragment");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;
    }

    // you will get data in this method where you can set value to your views
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("x","onActivityCreatedFragment");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        stringValue = getArguments().getString("stringValue");
        textView.setText(stringValue);



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("x","onCreateFragment");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        imagesResId = getArguments().getInt("images");
        stringValue = getArguments().getString("stringValue");

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make an ImageView show an image resource?

Comment: `ImageView imageResId = (ImageView) view.findViewById(image);
        imageResId.setImageResource(images[1]);` ..but now I get the same `image` displayed everywhere. How to properly set images from [ ] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: imageResId.setImageResource(imagesResId);

Comment: Thank you, great :)

Comment: hi there. could you please have a look at this post? have probles to implement boolean value to `onCreateView` and `if` statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062603/passing-different-images-every-second-fragment

Comment: hi there! Could you please to up vote this accepted answer? Need more privileges to earn

Comment: sure, no problem :) just i dont have enough rep yet to do so. upvoted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code of onActivityCreated() into onCreateView or onViewCreated().